# Set bazel invocation_id from command line

Tags: bazel, remote-execution

By default bazel produces UUID per invocation.

Some of the tools we're using use this Id to link their entities to the specific bazel invocation.

Is there a bazel flag to force our own Id instead of bazel's?
I looked in bazel official docs and couldn't find one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `--invocation_id=MY_ID` to any Bazel command to override the invocation id.